# Going from manual to automatically manage signing

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

I have a large project which has *'Automatically manage signing'* disabled. I want to enable it but is unsure what consequences it might have... Will it affect my existing certificates? It is the Apple Push Services certificates in particular that I'm afraid it might revoke.

Comment: This will take existing certificates if those certificates are  valid and matching bundle identifier otherwise it will create new certificate

Comment: @Savitha Just to be sure I got it right: it will not "destroy" any existing valid certificated?

Comment: it will not delete existing valid certificated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't revoke certificates. If certificates present it will consider it, else it will create automatically.